# REPOST - How can I search an Excel spreadsheet in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, app, mobile

Looking to be able to search the contents of an Excel spreadsheet from the SharePoint mobile app.

I have a spreadsheet with Postal Codes/Zip Codes with corresponding information. I would like to be able to search for a Postal/Zip Code as you would in Excel if you pressed "CTRL + F" FIND for example.

Is there a way to upload the spreadsheet and when you open it in the app, have the magnifying glass to click on or a field to type into without the need to install the Excel mobile app?

When I upload a test spreadsheet, it opens as like a PDF. User has "Read" permissions for the document library the spreadsheet is located in. I do not want the user to be able to edit any information, just serach/find/view it.

Thanks in advance,

(repost from guest account)